# Using UDP to let clients know server's existance, is it possible?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I am very new to network programming, so this might be a no brainer. What I was wondering is, I know TCP requires the client to know the IP of the server. But since UDP is connectionless server, is it still required? I mean can I make my server broadcast it's IP address on a specific port ( not necessary in the same LAN , also over internet) and make the clients listen to that port for any incoming requests and find get the IP of the server once a request is received ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to send packages on specific port over the LAN. But for the Internet no.

Comment: So it pretty much means there is no way for the client to no about the server's IP and connect to it unless I use a dedicated server in between them?

Comment: Either you can make some static variables in the client application that holds the information about the server's ip and port. Or you can make the client type the ip and the port.

Comment: There is another way to. Create a master server that will hold pointers for all the servers. So when someone downloads the server they can register their ip on the master server. And the client program will send a package to the master server and the master server will respond by sending all the ip address to the client. That is how many games do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using ARP/RARP if that gives you what you need. Coming to your question

Mind you both TCP and UDP require IP addresses binding the ip address to a port is called a socket and there can be TCP and UDP with the same port no.

You can do this according to what you said but then the server needs to know the client addresses

1. Create a connection from server to client
2. Send IP address of server to client
3. Client send data using just received Server IP

to work around this you can use the broadcast address of the network and have the clients listen to it, just check what your broadcast address is.

What you are trying to do is similar to a DHCP server.